# Install package managers over SSH & FTP

Tags: linux, apt-get

i have an device running on Pure Linux, there is no Package installer installed on that, the only thing i have is SSH and therefore also an Terminal. Commands like apt-get, dpkg, yum dont work.

How do i install apt-get over SSH? I've saw some suggestions that use yum, make or dpkg to install apt-get, but since i've neither of them...

Comment: Ask your administrator of the machine.

Comment: Download the source code of your package , ./configure  , make and sudo make install

Comment: make is also not installed

Comment: Is gcc installed? If not, cross-compile gcc for your machine, and copy the binaries. Then compile make and copy the binaries. Then download the sources of your packages, configure, make, sudo make install. Or you can cross-compile on your machine the package and copy the executables installed with make install. You have to take care or installing all dependencies manually.

Comment: gcc is installed, but it seems like that is very complicated to find the source code, compile, etc

Answer (score 0):

For debian based systems exists a tool called apt-offline. That's perfect in that scenario.

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/apt/apt-offline/

Comment: ok so i got to download an apt-offline.deb file... but i need dpkg to install it... Any other idea?

Comment: Where is the problem with the manual installation. IMO it has small dependencies. After you have installed it you can use it to modify your package system w/ external packages.